# Symfony2 app.php works but not app_dev.php

Tags: caching, symfony, deployment, permissions, capifony

I've deployed my Symfony2 project to my development server and want to run the dev environment.

Everything is running fine if I use /app.php but if I try app_dev.php I get a 404 error:

The requested URL /app_dev.php was not found on this server.

Below is a copy of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It works fine on my local machine, just not on my development server, any ideas why?

My /cache and /logs directories are both have 777 permissions and are owned by www-data:

```
drwxrwxrwx+ 4 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 15 11:46 cache
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 15 11:05 logs
```

dev and prod within these directories are exactly the same.

Comment: Are you trying to open the dev environment in the dev server from the server itself or from your local computer?

Comment: I'm browsing to the dev environment (app_dev.php) which is hosted on the dev server from my local computer

Answer (score 7):

Check your app_dev.php it has a restriction to deny access to the dev environment from other computers than the server itself.

This is for security reasons, if you deploy to a production server and a user would have access to dev env, then he/she could know a lot about your application.

```
// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

You must add your IP to that array, or remove the whole thing (I wouln't recommend that).

Always remember passing the dev variable to AppKernel. `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);`

Comment: Thanks @xr09. I have 3 external servers, development, staging and production, would you recommend I use the dev environment on my development server then or not?

Comment: @user1961082 In your dev server is ok (it is made for that after all), but remember setting the rules on deploy to avoid an accident in the production one.

Comment: so dev env for local machine and development server, test for staging and prod for production? I'm using Capifony with the Capistrano multi-stage extension so can I set this within my development.rb script or do I have to do it directly in app_dev.php?

Comment: You should edit your app_dev.php to add your local IP, yes dev is for local and dev. server, test is almost the same without the debug toolbar and the verbose logging, check you app/config/config[dev|test].yml and check the differences to see what is enabled in each environment.

Comment: sorry, when you say add my local IP, do you mean the IP of my local machine rather than the server? I.e whatismyip.com ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's even getting this far because I'm getting a 404 error rather than a 403. I've also tried adding my local IP as well as the dev server IP but still no joy?!

Comment: The apache conf is the same on both?

Comment: OK I've realised that app_dev.php is not being deployed. It's within my GIT repository in github but when I deploy using Capifony for some reason it's not pulling this file from github?!

Comment: Yes looks like capifony doesn't deploy those by default, may be this thread will help. https://github.com/everzet/capifony/issues/312